# Banning ID questions

Tags: discussion

I'm prepared to get downvoted into oblivion, but as the 6th highest rep guy here I think this should at least be heard.

I just saw that ID questions are no longer allowed.  This decision was based on a post that was seen by 854 users.  Yes, that post got 854 views.  Are views unique?  That I'm not sure, so it may have even been less actual users but I'll assume they're unique.  There's approximately (I didn't count, but used some basic math to compute) 32,632 users of this site, for a view rate of just less than 3%.  22 people upvoted the request, for a participation rate of 0.07%.  And based on 0.07% of the users, we decided to ban ID questions.

I'm not a big Meta user, but one of the most invaluable assets of this site to me has always been the ability to have someone identify a movie for me that I could then go back and enjoy.  This isn't LMGTFY, this is supposed to be a wealth of **experts** who help users.  I wouldn't go to SO and ask a question about programming if I could just google it myself.  This is, I thought, 65,264 eyes, some of whom have probably seen the movie in question and can tell you what it is from memory.  If you say, "There's a movie, a comedy, and all I remember was some drunk Asian kid in a tree yelling 'Oh Sexy girlfriend!'", I can tell you right off the bat that it's Sixteen Candles.  If you don't know it, don't answer it.  Don't google it.  It's not that hard.  Not every question gets answered on any SE site, which is why the [tumbleweed](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tumbleweed) badge exists.

I'd like to see ID questions get back to being allowed, and I'd like to hear from people who also want to see them allowed.  How much do you rely on this site for those types of questions?  How important are they to your experience here?

Comment: I have no problem with people questioning the decision either here or on the previous question that Ankit links to.  However, as the moderator who disliked id questions the least, even I can't dispute that the lack of interest in defending id questions was striking.  854 unique views (and I do believe it is unique) is actually quite high - most of the 32k users are unregistered 'one post' users.  We really can't force users to use meta and vote - but there was literally no responses to the 'checking in' post defending them when the decision was made.

Comment: Was it linked in the "Hot Topics" section on the main site?  I have to admit, I didn't know anything about it until I saw it referenced in the comments of an ID question.  I guess I should be in Meta more often, but 12 of my 82 questions here are [tag:identify-this-movie] questions.  That's 1 out of every 7.  I rely on that tag a lot.

Comment: @JohnnyBones Yes, for over a month.

Comment: Let's congratulate Walt for hitting 100K rep!  What's his top tag?  IDENTIFY-THIS-MOVIE.  67% of his posts are in that tag.  But that's OK, we can get rid of it.

Comment: Not sure what that's got to do with issue and its problems at hand, though.

Comment: "I wouldn't go to SO and ask a question about programming if I could just google it myself." Well, you're supposed to do that anyway, since chances are someone has asked it before and gotten an answer. "65,264 eyes, some of whom have probably seen the movie in question and can tell you what it is from memory." What is the average view count of an ID question? What % of them get significant numbers? How many users have filters that prevent them from viewing ID questions?

Comment: Just FYI, views as counted by SE aren't unique, so it was actually less than 854 users who viewed that question (cc @iandotkelly). You can test this out for yourself by going to an old, little-viewed question and refreshing the page every 15 minutes; the views count will increase each time.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Yeah, and it's a moot point that the only reason I ever came here was to ask an ITM question, let alone the fact that I've probably discovered 20 or 30 great movies simply because the premise in an ITM question sounded cool (and Walt probably dug up the name :oD ).  Whatevs.  I'm not as interested in this stack anymore without those questions.

Comment: @Randal'Thor ... ok - I did an experiment over a shorter period and didn't see an increase.  So clearly its not every single page refresh or per user.  Thanks for the info.

Comment: @JohnnyBones .... it would be sad to see you less around here - your contribution over the years has been very significant.  While I understand ID questions will be missed by you and others - they do form only a small part of your overall posts and reputation here.  :(